# Maximum in List of Records

Tags: elm

Say I have a List of records in elm:

```
[ { id = 1, magnitude = 100 }
, { id = 3, magnitude = 300 }
, { id = 2, magnitude = 200 } ]
```

and I want to get the record with the greatest magnitude value (300). What is a good way of doing this?

The [docs](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/List#maximum) gives an example of using the "maximum" -method, but it uses a simple list of integers. How is it done with records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update** based on recommendation from @robertjlooby

There is a function called [`maximumBy`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/list-extra/latest/List-Extra#maximumBy) which does exactly this in elm-community/list-extra. Example:

```elm
List.Extra.maximumBy .magnitude list
```

**Original Answer**

There are a few ways to achieve this.

This first way is more concise but it involves sorting the whole list, reversing it, then taking the head.

```elm
maxOfField : (a -> comparable) -> List a -> Maybe a
maxOfField field =
  List.head << List.reverse << List.sortBy field
```

If you want something that's more efficient and only traverses the list once, here's a more efficient version:

```elm
maxOfField : (a -> comparable) -> List a -> Maybe a
maxOfField field =
  let f x acc =
    case acc of
      Nothing -> Just x
      Just y -> if field x > field y then Just x else Just y 
  in List.foldr f Nothing
```

An example of it in use:

```elm
list =
  [ { id = 1, magnitude = 100 }
  , { id = 3, magnitude = 300 }
  , { id = 2, magnitude = 200 } ]

main =
  text <| toString <| maxOfField .magnitude list
```

Comment: Great Chad, thanks. I suppose using List.tail would work too - right?

Comment: List.tail << List.sortBy field

Comment: `List.tail` returns everything but the first element. You could achieve it with `last` from the [elm-community/list-extra](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/list-extra/2.0.1/List-Extra#last) package, though I was trying to avoid external packages in my answer

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks again.

Comment: If you're going to use the list-extra package though, you could just use [maximumBy](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/list-extra/2.0.1/List-Extra#maximumBy) which does this exact thing.
`List.Extra.maximumBy .magnitude list`

Comment: Thanks for the List.Extra update to your answer @ChadGilbert. That's the simple lazy kind of thing I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version that uses foldl and a default record:

```
bigger =
    let
        choose x y =
            if x.magnitude > y.magnitude then
                x
            else
                y
    in
        List.foldl choose {id = 0, magnitude = 0} items
```

Answer (score 1):

Sebastian's answer add an arbitrary start value which could cause a problem if all your magnitudes were negative. I would adjust to

```
bigger items =
    case items of 
        [] -> []
        (h :: []) -> h
        (h :: tail) ->
            let
                choose x y =
                    if x.magnitude > y.magnitude then
                        x
                    else
                        y
            in
                List.foldl choose h tail
```